# How to get GoPro HiLight tag in mp4 video in Android or Java

Tags: java, android, mp4parser, gopro

I manually added tags to mp4 video using GoPro - Quik.

According to [Chriki answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/884727/584689) and [GoProInfo.cpp](https://github.com/hypoxic/GoProInfo/blob/master/GoProInfo.cpp)
HiLight tags are stored in box type `HMMT` in milliseconds of mp4 video.

```
Path = `moov\udta\HMMT`
```

But I didn't found any tag milliseconds using [sannies/mp4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) code

```
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

    ReadableByteChannel chanel = Channels.newChannel(in);
```

I continue my R&D and got result for this code

```
IsoFile isoFile = new IsoFile(chanel);
                MovieBox movieBox = isoFile.getMovieBox();
                List<UserDataBox> userDataBoxes = movieBox.getBoxes(UserDataBox.class);

                stringBuilder.append("moov>UserBoxes:\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < userDataBoxes.size(); i++) {
                    stringBuilder.append(userDataBoxes.get(i));
                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                    UserDataBox erDataBox = userDataBoxes.get(i);
                    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < erDataBox.getBoxes().size(); i1++) {
                        stringBuilder.append(erDataBox.getBoxes().get(i));
                        stringBuilder.append("\n");
                    }
                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                }
```

Output:

```
moov>UserBoxes:
UserDataBox[MetaBox[HandlerBox[handlerType=mdir;name=��];AppleItemListBox[org.mp4parser.boxes.apple.AppleEncoderBox@619e00b]]]
    MetaBox[HandlerBox[handlerType=mdir;name=��];AppleItemListBox[org.mp4parser.boxes.apple.AppleEncoderBox@619e00b]]
```

**update:** I got `HMMT` with [isoviewer](https://github.com/sannies/isoviewer).
It is using following library

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.mp4parser</groupId>
            <artifactId>isoparser</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.14</version>
        </dependency>
```

Problem still not resolved cause
`com.googlecode.mp4parser` IsoFile class doesn't have constructor for `ReadableByteChannel` used for retrieving data from remote streams.

[image]

The real problem with library is that `sannies/mp4parser` doesn't returns `UnknownBox` from `UserDataBox` while `googlecode/mp4parser` does *but* there is only library that work with video url that sannies/mp4parser. Need to fix or any workaround.

Any solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with Quik software, it doesn't save tags inside file as I was expecting. It save tags against media unique id. You have to read tags from mp4 video that is created with GoPro Camera.

Getting from mp4 url code snippet

```
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new URL("http://localhost:6582?BRIDGE&%2FGOPR0175.MP4&GOPR0175.MP4&80898399").openConnection().getInputStream());
GoProTagsBox tags = GoProUtil.getHilights(inputStream);

stringBuilder.append("Count: "+tags.getCount());
if(tags.getHiLights() != null){
    for (long l : tags.getHiLights()) {
        stringBuilder.append("\nHiLight: "+l);
    }
}
```

Getting from GoPro mp4 file code snippet

```
GoProTagsBox tags = GoProUtil.getHilights(new RandomAccessFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/GOPR0175.MP4", "r"));
```

Working fine in both cases.

Using https://github.com/Qamar4P/JaadAndroid android versions of [jaad](https://github.com/dant3/jaad)